# How to create in a 2-dimentionals array all combinations from 2 different array

Tags: python, algorithm

I have to create a multiple dimensional list that looks like this :

```
[[[1,R],[1,R]],[[1,B],[1,B]],[[2,R],[1,B]],[[2,R],[2,B]]]...
```

From two lists :

`[1,2]` and `[R,B]`

My objective is to create all the possible combinations.

I've done something that is working.
with a while, but when the number of combinations is huge it takes so much time. For exemple when i have n(it is the number of color) = 5
And N = 6 --> RandomedColor= [Red,white,black,green,Yellow] and liste2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6] it will take at least 5 mins to be done.

```py
def Create_All_list_from_n(N): #Create all possible combinations of numbers with colors. if n = 2, and N = 5 then, there will be 2**5 combinations.
    all_list_of_N = []
    while(len(all_list_of_N) != n**N):     
        current_list = []
        for i in range(1,N+1):
            current_list.append([random.choice(RandomedColors),i])
        if current_list not in all_list_of_N:
            all_list_of_N.append(current_list)
        print(all_list_of_N)
        print(len(all_list_of_N))
    return all_list_of_N
```

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `product` and `combinations_with_replacement` from `itertools`

```
from itertools import product, combinations_with_replacement
x = [1,2]
y = ['R','B']
products = [list(i) for i in product(x,y)]
print([list(i) for i in combinations_with_replacement(products,2)])
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 'R'], [1, 'R']], [[1, 'R'], [1, 'B']], [[1, 'R'], [2, 'R']], [[1, 'R'], [2, 'B']], [[1, 'B'], [1, 'B']], [[1, 'B'], [2, 'R']], [[1, 'B'], [2, 'B']], [[2, 'R'], [2, 'R']], [[2, 'R'], [2, 'B']], [[2, 'B'], [2, 'B']]]
```

Comment: As you can see in his example, he has the combination `[1, 'R'], [1, 'R']`. As per my answer, you should use `combinations_with_replacement()` instead of `combinations()`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be implemented relatively efficiently with `itertools.product()`.

For example:

```
import itertools


print(list(itertools.product([1, 2], ['R', 'B'])))
# [(1, 'R'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'R'), (2, 'B')]
```

and then you can use that to generate the replicas you need.

Answer (score 0):

To handle combinatory problems, `itertools` is very usefull. It offers all the required function to generate the combinations.

The idea is to use `product` and then `combinations_with_replacement`.

```
L1 = [1,2]
L2 = ["R" ,"B"]

import itertools

products = list(itertools.product(L1, L2))
combinations = list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(products, 2))
```

Output:

```
[((1, 'R'), (1, 'R')),
 ((1, 'R'), (1, 'B')),
 ((1, 'R'), (2, 'R')),
 ((1, 'R'), (2, 'B')),
 ((1, 'B'), (1, 'B')),
 ((1, 'B'), (2, 'R')),
 ((1, 'B'), (2, 'B')),
 ((2, 'R'), (2, 'R')),
 ((2, 'R'), (2, 'B')),
 ((2, 'B'), (2, 'B'))]
```